# OpenLdap with ppolicy plugin: is it possible to auto-remove pwdFailureTime attributes?

Tags: openldap

OpenLdap 2.4.* is in use, with ppolicy plugin

I noticed that pwdFailureTime multivalue attribute is being added to LDAP database, but looks like it is never deleted.

Is there simple way to make older values of that attribute to get automatically deleted? I am not happy seeing database keeping more and more of those records.

I can filter the LDAP backups from spurious values and get the whole DB re-added using slapadd, but simpler solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `pwdFailureTime` attribute is deleted when a user successfully binds.

It's added to each user object to track how many failed binds have occurred since the last successful bind, part of the whole point of using the `ppolicy` overlay so dumping and reloading the database to get rid of them doesn't really make any sense.

The `pwdMaxFailure` attribute in your policy object sets how many failed binds are tracked before the action defined by the `pwdLockout` attribute is triggered. It defaults to 0 which means an unlimited number of failures are tracked (which might explain the behaviour you're seeing), but if you then set it to a non-zero number you will then trigger `pwdLockout` which defaults to true after that many failures. This will mean users get locked out of their account, however if user objects are accumulating `pwdFailureTime` attribute values to the degree that you're uncomfortable seeing them then it means they're not successfully binding anyway.

You can also try setting the `pwdFailureCountInterval` attribute on your policy object which according to the documentation will reset the failed password count after `value` seconds which I would assume clears any `pwdFailureTime` attributes to achieve that, but then you're changing the heuristics for tracking failed binds.

Comment: It does indeed clear excess `pwdFailureTime` attributes, as the count of these *is* the failed password count.